# how to print the output of group_concat function

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

How to print the output of this query:

```
 $NOTicoun=mysqli_query($conn,"select group_concat(distinct session_id) 
 from fk_views where comment !='' and onid='3738'");
```

I tried: `mysqli_data_seek`, but the result is not setisfactory. In the earlier version of php we could use `mysql_result` function, but it is not availabe in this version of php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an `Alias`

```
select group_concat(distinct session_id) as yourAlias
```

Then fetch the associative array and access it with that

```
$row['yourAlias']
```

And of course there are other ways too

Comment: hii,
Thankyou for your valuable reply it worked ..:)
i'll accept the anser once 8 minutes limitaation gets over and can you please tell me one more way of printing it please .